# Eclipse is not starting after installation of plugins

Tags: eclipse, sdk

I downloaded some plugins from Help>Install New Software in eclipse.After the download it was to be restarted.After restart it doesn't open up.Says an error has occurred,see the log file 1363836429331.
My eclipse.ini is-

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Declipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
```

I use Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: ...and what's in the log file it told you to look at?

Comment: what does the error log say? can you copy/paste here?